# What is "iscraped" in Apache LOG (/var/log/messages)

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

For example this is all I see in the log. Log is now several GB big :S

I've tryed to google for a solution, but I've found none :(

```
Feb 10 09:41:53 vps2 iscraped[12861]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12861)
Feb 10 09:41:53 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12861 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:41:54 vps2 iscraped[12864]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12864)
Feb 10 09:41:54 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12864 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:41:55 vps2 iscraped[12867]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12867)
Feb 10 09:41:55 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12867 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:41:56 vps2 iscraped[12868]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12868)
Feb 10 09:41:56 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12868 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:41:57 vps2 iscraped[12869]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12869)
Feb 10 09:41:57 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12869 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:41:58 vps2 iscraped[12870]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12870)
Feb 10 09:41:58 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12870 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:41:59 vps2 iscraped[12875]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12875)
Feb 10 09:41:59 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12875 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:42:00 vps2 iscraped[12878]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12878)
Feb 10 09:42:00 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12878 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:42:01 vps2 iscraped[12902]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12902)
Feb 10 09:42:01 vps2 iscraped[20748]: #SCRAPED# ALERT: child 12902 is !dead!, will be restarted
Feb 10 09:42:02 vps2 iscraped[12923]: #SCRAPED# INFO: child started (12923)
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like it's something that's yanking lines from the Apache error log and feeding them to the system event log.. not finding anything in Google for that name, though.  Maybe custom to your service provider?

At any rate, I guess the question I'd have is: **are you having problems with your Apache service because of these dead child processes?  Or is the problem you're having just the fact that the log file is bloating to be too large because of all of these log entries?**

If it's just the log file size, you can probably adjust either your logrotate settings to be more appropriate to your log volume (how old is that several gig file?), or change the verbosity of your Apache logs.

Those logs do look problematic, though - what content is running within Apache?  Seems like requests are being run pretty much constantly that are killing those child processes?